# SQL matches interval counting from midnight

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

here is my sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules` (
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `interval_dur` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `last_schedule` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Field interval_dur contains value of seconds, so for example we can have records like:

```
2_5_hours   1   9000    1970-01-01 00:00:00
15_minutes  2   900 1970-01-01 00:00:00
1_minute    3   60  1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

For example I would like to filter out record 2_5_hours when:
last_schedule was at let say 5:00AM today, and now is after 07:30AM.
Or another example:
15_minutes when:
last_schedule was at 00:15AM today, and now is after 00:30AM.

Interval counts from midnight of course.

thanks!

Comment: You should store an additional column -- or better yet, have a lookup table -- that stores the duration in a common unit such as seconds or minutes.

Answer (score 0):

ah found the solution

```
SELECT s.*, DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as today_not, DATE_ADD(s.last_schedule, INTERVAL s.interval_dur DAY_SECOND) < now()
from 
schedules s
WHERE 
s.last_schedule <= DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 DAY) OR
DATE_ADD(s.last_schedule, INTERVAL s.interval_dur DAY_SECOND) < now()
```